# Regular expression not matching specific string

Tags: regex

My use case is as follows: I would like to find all occurrences of something similar to this `/name.action`, but where the last part is not `.action` eg:

- name.actoin - should match
- name.action - should not match
- nameaction - should not match

I have this:
`/\w+.\w*`
to match two words separated by a dot, but I don't know how to add 'and do not match .action'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you need to escape your `.` character as that's taken as `any character` in Regex.

Secondly, you need to add in a `Match if suffix is not present` group - signified by the `(?!)` syntax.

You may also want to put a circumflex `^` to signify the start of a new line and change your `*` (any repetitions) to a `+` (one or more repititions).

`^/\w+\.(?!action)\w+` is the finished Regex.

Comment: In most regex implementations, the `.` does not match `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Whether `\w` applies to ASCII alone depends on the programming language used, and sometimes to regex compilation flags — e.g., in some, you need a `/u` or `(?u)`, while in others (like Java) even that is insufficient to get include Unicode alphanums.

Answer (score 3):

```
^\w+\.(?!action)\w*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot character.

Comment: That's just a (small) part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\w+\.(?!action).*
```

Note the trailing `.*` Not sure what you want to do after the action text.

See also [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a [zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html#item__pattern_).  This will let you look ahead in the string, and match based on the negation of a word.

So the regex you'd need (including the escaped . character) would look something like:

```
/name\.(?!action)/
```