# Angular regex email domain accept and not accept validation

Tags: angular, regex

Indiviual Email Id accept only the gmail and yahoo domain
Business Email Id not accept the gmail and yahoo domain

Indiviual Email Id regex validation is working and Business Email Id regex validation not working.

**How to fix Business Email Id regex validation?**

please check the stackblitz example

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="registerProfileForm" novalidate>
  <span><b>Indiviual Email Id accept only the gmail and yahoo domain</b></span>
  <div>
    <label for="vendorEmailId">Indiviual Email Id<span class="required-field">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" formControlName="indiviualEmailId"  type="email">
  </div>
  <span class="text-danger"
                  *ngIf="registerProfileForm.controls?.indiviualEmailId?.hasError('pattern')">
                  Please enter a valid email domain name 
                  </span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <span><b>Business Email Id not accept  the gmail and yahoo domain</b></span>

  <div>
    <label for="vendorEmailId">Business Email Id<span class="required-field">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" formControlName="businessEmailId"  type="email">
  </div>
  <span class="text-danger"
                    *ngIf="registerProfileForm.controls?.businessEmailId?.hasError('pattern')">
                    Please enter a valid email domain name 
                    </span>
</form>
```

ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  registerProfileForm: FormGroup;
  emailValidatorBusiness = /^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(!gmail|!yahoo)\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/;

  emailValidatorIndiviual = /^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(gmail|yahoo)\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$/;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
      this.registerProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        indiviualEmailId: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailValidatorIndiviual)]),
        businessEmailId: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailValidatorBusiness)])
      })
    }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3sbonz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Did you test the regex in isolation, e.g. on [regex-planet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyypw11m3r)? What were the failing test-cases?

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative: Use Angular validators

e.g. [`Validators.email()`](https://v6.angular.io/api/forms/Validators#email)
as explained in:
[Angular 5 - form validation e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182864/angular-5-form-validation-e-mail)

There you can find [an answer combining validators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56380871/5730279) like:

```
this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
           Validators.required,
           Validators.email
    ]))
});
```

In a second step you can test the primarily valid email for the host.
E.g. with a regex and different assertions per case:

- assert business email **does not** match `gmail|yahoo`
- assert private email **does** match `gmail|yahoo`

See:

- [Regular expression not matching specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881608/regular-expression-not-matching-specific-string)
- [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

### Fixing the regex in isolation

Email-validation using regex is hard:
[How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Still, if the regex is not working, let's compare them:

#### Not Working

**emailValidatorBusines**, expected acceptance criteria::

1. **not** match any *gmail* domain
2. **not** match any *yahoo* domain

```
^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(!gmail|!yahoo)\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$
```

Different part: `(!gmail|!yahoo)`

#### Working

**emailValidatorIndiviual**, expected acceptance criteria:

1. **match** any *gmail* domain
2. **match** any *yahoo* domain

```
^[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z{|}~](\.?[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_a-z`{|}~])*@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(gmail|yahoo)\.[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+$
```

Different part: `(gmail|yahoo)`

Comment: emailValidatorBusines not working.